# programmatically press UIkeyboard return key

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I would like to know if you can call the return (enter) key of the UIkeyboard programmatically. I have created a paste method which pastes a cached value into a UITextField, what I want to do then is go to the next UITextField.

I can do this if I hit the enter key on the UIkeyboard I was woundering if I can programmatically use the enter key.

Comment: Do you actually need to press the key? Can't you just take whatever action you would be taking in response to the key being pressed?

Comment: no I dont want to press the UIkeyboard key I want to action the return key programatically when a UIButton is pressed.

Comment: So what's preventing you from doing whatever it is you need to do when that other button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use UIResponder to jump to the next text field?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

As to simulate key press, his might help http://blog.lazerwalker.com/blog/2013/10/17/more-fun-with-simulated-ios-events-keypresses/
But he uses private apis, and it only works before iOS7.